# Is it possible for the commit and reveal transaction to be on the same block?

Tags: transaction-fees, transaction-selection, ordinals

I'm new to the inscribing process and I noticed there were two transactions required for inscribing. Is it possible to have these on the same block? or is there a way to control the tx fee on the reveal tx to help increase the possibility of it to be on the same block?

Answer (score 1):

If you give the second transaction a higher fee rate, the two transactions will be treated as one "package" by any reasonable transaction selection algorithm and will almost certainly be mined in the same block. However, there's no way to actually prevent a miner to only mine the first transaction but not the second.